# Is this chord progression correct for "false ending" (Ⅴ-Ⅵ)?

Tags: chords, chord-progressions

[image]Maroon 5 - She Will Be Loved Chords
key:E♭m
[Cm→A♯]←I want to check this chord progression.

link ; https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/maroon-5/she-will-be-loved-chords-995857

Comment: If only the site was accurate enough to use the correct chord names, you'd realise it's the same two as your last question. Cm > ***Bb***. There's no A# in key Eb. But I visit, using your link, and there's no Cm or A# in sight! What's going on?

Comment: @Tim - site has a transpose button at the bottom. Pick any key you like, so long as it only has sharps in it ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - as I suspected. Guitarists can't play flat notes/chords, everyone (except us) knows that...

Answer (score 1):

You have your Roman numerals backwards. The Cm comes first. Also the VI should either be in lower case or have an m like so: vi or VIm. The chords on the verses are actually Cm to Bb7. The guitar plays an Ab note on the 3+ And also sometimes lightly on the 1+ and 2+ with the D. This doesn’t affect the analysis much though. It is a deceptive cadence since the chords loop and the Bb7 resolves to the Cm instead of I or Eb, the relative major. The exception is going into the chorus it actually is a regular cadence, a V-I, Bb7-Eb

The song goes to Eb for the chorus: Eb Bb(4+3) Cm Ab (I V vi IV). That means you can interpret it one of two ways.

1. The entire song is in Eb. In that case the verses are vi-V7 (or VIm-V7)
2. The verses are in Cm and modulate to the relative major for the choruses. In that case the verses are i-VII7 (or Im-VII7)

Either analysis is acceptable, it depends on how you like to approach or conceptualize it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is this chord progression correct for "false ending" (Ⅴ-Ⅵ)?

Yes, V-VI is a "false ending" (deceptive cadence), but ...

#### This isn't a false ending.

The song just oscillates between two chords, and there's no sense that the tonic should be elsewhere. The conditions for a deceptive cadence aren't present.